# Python / DataReader / Yahoo - with pandas' Panel deprecated, how can I instead bring stock data into multiindexed dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, datareader, multi-index

the pandas datareader tool which accesses the Yahoo Finance stock data seems to pull data directly into a `panel` - which I think believe will be dropped from pandas soon. Does anyone know how to pull data into a `multiindexed dataframe` in lieu of a panel?

```
import pandas_datareader as data
stock_data = data.DataReader(['AAPL','GE'], 'yahoo', datetime(2017,1,1), datetime.now())

In [121]: stock_data

Out [121]: 
    <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
    Dimensions: 6 (items) x 91 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
    Items axis: Open to Adj Close
    Major_axis axis: 2017-01-03 00:00:00 to 2017-05-12 00:00:00
    Minor_axis axis: AAPL to GE
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Panel.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.to_frame.html):

```
df = stock_data.to_frame()
```

Also function [`Panel.transpose`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.transpose.html) can be helpful if need swap `MultiIndex`es in indexes and columns.

Comment: hi jez - i was concerned that panel.to_frame() wouldn't work once panel is removed from pandas altogether.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But then in future developers of  pandas_datareader change function for return MultiIndex or xarray [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-panel). But now if function return panel need convert it.

Comment: Also [there](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/297) is opened issue for it.